# Simple text reader (OCR) in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, ocr

I am trying to write a simple program to read a bmp image in gray scale.  I have a set of patterns (the whole alphabet except for 'I') and I want to match them.  I have problems doing this in Matlab.

What I got so far:

```
clear
clc

%set of patterns
BW1 = imread('alphabet.bmp');
patterns = bwlabel(~BW1);
patternStats = regionprops(patterns,'all');

patternNumber = size(patternStats);
imagePatternArray = cell(patternNumber);

%make cell array of pattern vectors
for i = 1:1:patternNumber
  imageMatrix = patternStats(i).Image;
  imageVector = imageMatrix(:);
  imagePatternArray{i} = imageVector;
end  

%set of chars
BW2 = imread('text.bmp');
text = bwlabel(~BW2);
textStats = regionprops(text,'all');

letterNumber = size(textStats);
imageLetterArray = cell(letterNumber);

%make cell array of text vectors
for i = 1:1:letterNumber
  imageMatrix = textStats(i).Image;
  imageVector = imageMatrix(:);
  imageLetterArray{i} = imageVector;
end

%lookup table
charSet =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
```

Now I would like to compare the pattern vectors with the given vector, but they have different sizes.

How can I do this?  Is there some special compare function?  Should I add 0s to the end and then calculate the distance with `pdist`?

Comment: What you probably want to do is use correlation at different scales (sizes.) Thats about the simplest OCR that exists. Look at the function normxcorr2, specifically the examples in matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The soultion

```
clear
clc

%set of patterns
BW1 = imread('alphabet.bmp');
patterns = bwlabel(~BW1);
patternStats = regionprops(patterns,'all');

patternNumber = size(patternStats);
imagePatternArray = cell(patternNumber);

%make cell array of pattern Matrices
for i = 1:1:patternNumber
  imageMatrix = patternStats(i).Image;
  imageMatrix = imresize(imageMatrix, [25 20]);
  imagePatternArray{i} = imageMatrix;
end  

%set of chars
BW2 = imread('kol_2.bmp');
BW2Gray = rgb2gray(BW2); %convert text to grayscale bmp - 0 OR 1
text = bwlabel(~BW2Gray);
textStats = regionprops(text,'all'); 

letterNumber = size(textStats);
imageLetterArray = cell(letterNumber);

%make cell array of text Matrices
for i = 1:1:letterNumber
  imageMatrix = textStats(i).Image;
  imageMatrix = imresize(imageMatrix, [25 20]);
  imageLetterArray{i} = imageMatrix;
end

%white spaces
whiteSpacesIndexes = [];

for i = 1:letterNumber - 1
  firstLetterBox = textStats(i).BoundingBox;
  positionFirstVector = [firstLetterBox(1), firstLetterBox(2)];  

  secondLetterBox = textStats(i+1).BoundingBox;
  positionSecondVector = [secondLetterBox(1), secondLetterBox(2)];

  distanceVector = positionSecondVector - positionFirstVector;
  distance = norm(distanceVector)
  % if the distance between is bigger that letter width plus 1/3 of width, it is a whitespace
  bothLettersSize = firstLetterBox(3)  + secondLetterBox(3);
  noSpaceDistance =  bothLettersSize - bothLettersSize * 0.25; % - 25 per cent (heuristic value)

  if (distance > noSpaceDistance) %&& (abs(distanceVector(2)) > 1.0)
      whiteSpacesIndexes = [whiteSpacesIndexes, i + 1];
  end 
end

compareVector = size(patternNumber);
indexArray = size(letterNumber);

for i = 1:1:letterNumber
    for j = 1:1:patternNumber        
           correlationMatrix = normxcorr2(imagePatternArray{j},imageLetterArray{i});           
          compareVector(j) = max(abs(correlationMatrix(:)));
    end    
        [correlationMax,correlationIndex] = max(compareVector);
       indexArray(i) = correlationIndex;
end

%lookup table
charSet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

%outPut stream
outPut = size(letterNumber);
for i = 1:1:letterNumber
   outPut(i) = charSet(indexArray(i));
end

whiteSpaceNumber = size(whiteSpacesIndexes,2);

whiteSpacesIndexes = whiteSpacesIndexes + (0:numel(whiteSpacesIndexes)-1)
nFinal = numel(outPut)+numel(whiteSpacesIndexes );      %# New length of result with blanks
newstr = blanks(nFinal);                                %# Initialize the result as blanks
newstr(setdiff(1:nFinal,whiteSpacesIndexes )) = outPut
```

I fairly simple and have some drawback like

- does not read 'I'
- reads only horizonatal strip of text
- white space detecting should be improved