# Insert white spaces into char array

Tags: arrays, matlab, string, char

I have char array(vector) of chars and I want to insert white spaces in specific order.

For example I have

```
 ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','O']
```

and vector with indexes of white spaces

```
[7 12] % white spaces should be add to 7 and 12 indexes (original string)
```

and want to have

```
 ['A','B','C','D','E','F',' ','G','H','J','K', 'L', ' ','M','N','O']
```

Is there some build-in function? I started with nested loop to itarate the array and instert ' ', but it looks ugly.

Comment: How do you identify where the blanks should go? A set of indices for the *output array*? A set of indices for the *input array* to add the blanks after?

Comment: I have an array of indexes [7, 12 .... and I want to put white space there and "move horizonatly" the rest of the string"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have indices into your vector where you want the blanks to be inserted, you could do the following:

```
>> str = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNO';                %# Your string
>> index = [7 12];                        %# Indices to insert blanks
>> index = index+(0:numel(index)-1);      %# Adjust for adding of blanks
>> nFinal = numel(str)+numel(index);      %# New length of result with blanks
>> newstr = blanks(nFinal);               %# Initialize the result as blanks
>> newstr(setdiff(1:nFinal,index)) = str  %# Fill in the string characters

newstr =

ABCDEF GHJKL MNO
```

Comment: thx but this is not execly what I wanted, maybe I wasn't clear. It puts 7 correctly, but 12 index is taken form the new array with a space - Should be ABCDEF GHJKL MNO.

Comment: @lukas: I've updated my answer, so it should work for you now. You should probably edit the question to add the extra detail about your indexing scheme.

Comment: awesome. I need it for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558005/simple-text-reader-ocr-in-matlab/5572667#5572667

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to insert spaces at specific indices?

```
chars = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','O'];
%insert space after index 6 and after index 10 in chars
charsWithWhitespace = [chars(1:6), ' ', chars(7:10), ' ', chars(11:end)];
```

Comment: This works for the specific example, but how would it generalize to an arbitrary set of indices?