# Matlab - OCR function digits recognition

Tags: matlab, ocr, digit

Recently I'm trying to detect digits from images in Matlab and I encountered a problem: a clear visible '1' on photo below (and many similar)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkTMN.jpg)

is not detected by 'ocr' function. Could you tell me how can I preprocess this image to allow this funcion recognize such a numbers?

Comment: The docs for `ocr` state *remove any text rotations greater than +/- 10 degrees, to improve recognition results.* so maybe try that? Otherwise the docs point to this document http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-optical-character-recognition-for-custom-fonts.html at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might find this example on the [mathworks](http://au.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/recognize-text-using-optical-character-recognition-ocr.html) web-site helpful. The second example of looking for digits on a picture of calculator is particularly relevant.

Applying the first trick they use (telling OCR you are expecting a block of text) results in the code below; which I found partially worked with the particular example image you linked above.

```
% Load your image
I = imread('tkTMN.jpg');

% Perform OCR, looking for a block of text:
results = ocr(I, 'TextLayout', 'Block');

% Display the recognized words
if ~isempty(results.Words)
    disp(results.Words);
else
    error('no words found');
end
```

For me, on matlab `8.6.0.267246 (R2015b)` this returned the word list:

```
'1'
'.'
'j'
```

So not perfect, but at least it found the '1'. The other pre-processing tricks suggested on the mathworks page might get you better results.

Comment: There is a very basic solution avoiding the matlab CV-toolbox provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558005/simple-text-reader-ocr-in-matlab. Also nice to understand the fundamentals of OCR algorithms.